# Compare image from Picturebox to SQL Image data type

Tags: sql-server, image, vb6

I have a code that saves an image from picturebox(image in vb6) to SQL the data type of that is Image and here is the output of that.

```
Column Name = Picture
```

[image]

My question is how can I compare the image from here

[image]

into my SQL Database? My goal here is to check if the image in `image3` exist in my database.

Here is my code and its not working.

```
Dim arrImageByte() As Byte
Dim strPhotoPath As String
strPhotoPath = Image3.Picture & ".jpg"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Open strPhotoPath For Binary As #1
ReDim arrImageByte(FileLen(strPhotoPath))
        fNum = FreeFile()
        Open strPhotoPath For Binary As #fNum
        Get #fNum, , arrImageByte
        Close fNum

   Text1.Text = FreeFile
   rs.Open "select * from tbl_image with (nolock) where CONVERT(varbinary,[picture]) = '" & Text1.Text & "'", sql, 1, 1, 1


If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
   MsgBox "Image exist"
Else
   MsgBox "Image does not exist."
End If
```

I think the best way to do this is to convert `image3` into binary (`Picture Column`) and do the select command.

Please I hope someone help me with this

TYSM

Comment: have you tried doing this using a stored proc? you might be trimming your messages etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I made a few changes and hope this helps.

1. I am using a command as I never trust the data to be safe, even if only I will ever use the program
2. I removed `WITH(NOLOCK)` this is bad for indexes and can decrease performance.
3. changed your if statement to be `>0` instead of `=0` because if you got results it would show image does not exist.

   ```
   Dim arrImageByte() As Byte
   Dim strPhotoPath As String
   strPhotoPath = Image3.Picture & ".jpg"
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

   Open strPhotoPath For Binary As #1
   ReDim arrImageByte(FileLen(strPhotoPath))
           fNum = FreeFile()
           Open strPhotoPath For Binary As #fNum
           Get #fNum, , arrImageByte
           Close fNum

      Text1.Text = FreeFile
      Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
      cmd.ActiveConnection = sql
      cmd.CommandText ="SELECT * FROM tbl_image where " & _ 
          "CONVERT(varbinary,[picture]) = CONVERT(varbinary,?)"
      cmd.Parameters(1)=Text1.Text
      rs = cmd.Execute()
   'Change this
   If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then 'instead of =
      MsgBox "Image exist"
   Else
      MsgBox "Image does not exist."
   End If
   ```